# Disabling a button if an immutable list contains empty value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If a user enters a blank value in a textbox, the button should be disabled.
I'm doing this check  using the following filter.But this does not work.Please advice.

```
                   <ALink href='javascript:void(0);'
                    className='button primary default-size' id='globalParametersCancel'
                    content={localeHelper.translate('iaSampling.iaGlobalConfiguration.reset')}
                    isDisabled={(!this.globalParameterChanged) && (!this.gaparameterlist?.find(x => x.value == ' '))}
                    onClick={this.reset} />
```

Comment: Do you use any js framework to rerender ? Is it reactjs or what?

Comment: @NghiNguyen i just set the state again by calling a method.

Comment: Why did you put `space` in  `' '`?

Comment: A bit hard to find the context of problem you're facing now? I don't know ALink is component is support isDisable or not? And how event effect to  this.globalParameterChanged and this.gaparameterlist state here ? Could you show more detail of your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using React you could do something like this, imagine you had an input field with an `onChange`. You can set the state in the change handler equal to `e.target.value`. When the state has changed, the `useEffect()` callback is called and will check if the input is valid. If the input is valid (you could do any validation you like, for example date, number, regular expression...), you set valid (`setValid(true)`).

```js
// callback after setting text
useEffect(() => {
  // do validation
  if (text) {
    setValid(true);
  } else {
    setValid(false);
  }
}, [text]);

const handleChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
  setText(e.target.value); // set text
};
```

Then, according to the `valid` boolean state value, you could render what you want, in this case a button, if not valid => display a message or whatever you like.

```js
const validDisplay = valid ? (
  <button onClick={handleClick}>submit</button>
) : (
  <span>Not valid!</span>
);
```

This is what your final `return` could look like.

```js
return (
  <div>
    <input value={text} onChange={handleChange}></input>
    <p>
      {validDisplay} {text}
    </p>
  </div>
);
```

I made a sandbox, you can try it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-austin-lw7rf?file=/src/App.js)